# Would a drawing of the rationals on a number line create the appearance of a line, nothing, or both?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, number-line

On a number line, the rationals are dense in R, meaning there are infinite rationals between rationals.

However, there are infinite undefined irrationals with a Lebesgue measure of 1.

So how do we describe the rationals on a number line? Would we get a "line", nothing, or both? Do points dense in R always create a line? Is there a paradox related to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely do not get a line due to infinitely many missing points.

You also do not get nothing because you have infinitely many points in your set. what you get is a dense subset of the real line.

The intersection of every interval of real line with your set is infinite and it is  dense in that interval.

You may call it a dust if you wish.

Comment: How would you graph this on a number line? If you graph it on a number line would you get what appears to be a line, nothing, or both?

Comment: We can not even get close to a reasonable graph of the dust on the real line. Our technology is not quite there yet. Both the set and its complement look like a line.

Comment: Why is such a graph possible? Is there any papers written on this? I know its pointless, just curious.

Comment: We can visualize it through our mathematical lens but we can not actually  draw it on a piece of paper. I am not aware of any articles on this subject but you may enjoy watching some videos on fractals and self similarity.